WIX membr erea app, adding to another collection when a new user signs up/registers
hoping I can get some help from someone. I have a wix page, using the members area app. and i've made another collection to store some new info about the users.
I'd like to use this ..
export function Members$FullData_afterUpdate(item, context) {
}
to update the other collection : members_info
with the field ID : loginEmail
so I can then add in the new fields to a page where they can update a new field called Locations and that new field will be a TAG field id is : arraystring
to update the other collection : members_info
with the field ID : loginEmail
so I can then add in the new fields to a page where they can update a new field called Locations and that new field will be a TAG field id is : arraystring
I added this to the data.js
`
export function wixMembers_onMemberCreated(event) {
    const loginEmail = event.entity.profile.loginEmail;
    const creationEventId = event.metadata.id;
  
  }


  import wixData from 'wix-data';

  // ...
  
  let toInsert = {
    "title":        "Mr.",
    "loginEmail":   "John@testing.com" 
  };
  
  wixData.insert("member_info", toInsert)
    .then((item) => {
  console.log(item); //see item below
      })
    .catch((err) => {
      console.log(err);
    });
 
`

